# Achiral system with Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya interaction?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, quantum-spin

From my tentative understanding, Dzyaloshinskii-Moriya (DM) interaction determines a certain chirality by its special mixed product form while its existence only requires the breaking of inversion symmetry.
It is said that it is ubiquitous in chiral magnets. However, noncentrosymmetric $\nRightarrow$ chiral in 3D in general.
So the question is whether there is any achiral system with DM interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the so-called polar magnet, e.g., VOSe$_2$O$_5$ as shown in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.237201).